# How to configure expiry of refresh tokens

Tags: security, configuration, refresh-token

I have heard that "Refresh tokens can be configured to expire in their associated Connected App by an org admin." Can anyone direct me to where in the UI this feature is available?
Thanks

Comment: what is your profile? If you are an admin you must see this at Setup > Manage Apps > Connected Apps > [YOUR APP]

Answer (score 1):

Setup > Manage Apps > Connected Apps > [YOUR APP] and see attached:

[image: Edit Refresh Token periodicity.]

Comment: Thanks but I don't see those at all, instead I see "IP Restrictions" and "Require Users to Log In" on the right under OAuth policies, which admittedly look similar, are they the same?